# How to remove duplicates only if consecutive in a string?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

For a string such as `'12233322155552'`, by removing the duplicates, I can get `'1235'`.

But what I want to keep is `'1232152'`, **only removing the consecutive duplicates.**

Answer (score 21):

```
import re

# Only repeated numbers
answer = re.sub(r'(\d)\1+', r'\1', '12233322155552')

# Any repeated character
answer = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', '12233322155552')
```

Comment: Use `r'(.)\1+'` to generalize this solution for any repeated character, and `r'(\S)\1+'` to any *non-whitespace* character.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `itertools`, here is the one liner

```
>>> s = '12233322155552'
>>> ''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(s))
'1232152'
```

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft / Amazon job interview type of question:
This is the pseudocode, the actual code is left as exercise.

```
for each char in the string do:
   if the current char is equal to the next char:
      delete next char
   else
     continue

return string
```

As a more high level, try (not actually the implementation):

```
for s in string:
  if s == s+1:  ## check until the end of the string
     delete s+1
```

Comment: Good call on not giving exact code (though Python is pretty darn close to pseudocode already).

Answer (score 7):

Hint: the itertools module is super-useful.  One function in particular, [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), might come in really handy here:

> itertools.groupby(iterable[, key])
>
> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from 
>   the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each
>   element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity
>   function and returns the element unchanged. Generally, the iterable
>   needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

So since strings are iterable, what you could do is:

```
use groupby to collect neighbouring elements
extract the keys from the iterator returned by groupby
join the keys together
```

which can all be done in one clean line..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't remove anything from a string in Python (google "Python immutable string" if this is not clear).

M first approach would be:

```
foo = '12233322155552'
bar = ''
for chr in foo:
    if bar == '' or chr != bar[len(bar)-1]:
        bar += chr
```

or, using the itertools hint from above:

```
''.join([ k[0] for k in groupby(a) ])
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for groupby. Off the cuff, something like:

```
from itertools import groupby
def remove_dupes(arg):
    # create generator of distinct characters, ignore grouper objects
    unique = (i[0] for i in groupby(arg))
    return ''.join(unique)
```

Cooks for me in Python 2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

```
number = '12233322155552'
temp_list = []


for item in number:   
   if len(temp_list) == 0:
      temp_list.append(item)

   elif len(temp_list) > 0:
      if  temp_list[-1] != item:
          temp_list.append(item)

print(''.join(temp_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a way:

```
def fix(a):
    list = []

    for element in a:
        # fill the list if the list is empty
        if len(list) == 0:list.append(element)
        # check with the last element of the list
        if list[-1] != element:  list.append(element)

    print(''.join(list))    


a= 'GGGGiiiiniiiGinnaaaaaProtijayi'
fix(a)
# output => GiniGinaProtijayi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = '12233322155552'
for i in t:
    dup = i+i
    t = re.sub(dup, i, t)
```

You can get final output as `1232152`