# How can I convert a unicode string into string literals in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, unicode

Python2.7:
I would like to do something unusual. Most people want to convert string literals to more human-readable strings. I would like to convert the following list of unicode strings into their literal forms:

- hallöchen
- Straße
- Gemüse
- freø̯̯nt

to their codepoint forms that look something like this:

\u3023\u2344

You'll notice that freø̯̯nt has two inverted breves below the ø. I would like to convert especially that word into its literal form, such that I can use REGEX to remove the extra breve.

I am not sure what the terminology is for these things—please correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You'll notice that freø̯̯nt has two inverted breves below the ø. I would like to convert especially that word into its literal form, such that I can use REGEX to remove the extra breve.

You don't need `codecs.encode(unicode_string, 'unicode-escape')` in this case. There are no string literals in memory only string objects.

Unicode string is a sequence of Unicode codepoints in Python. The same user-perceived characters can be written using different codepoints e.g., `'Ç'` could be written as `u'\u00c7'` and  `u'\u0043\u0327'`.

You could use [`NFKD` Unicode normalization form](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) to make sure "breves" are separate in order not to miss them when they are duplicated:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import unicodedata

s = u"freø̯̯nt"
# remove consecutive duplicate "breves"
print(re.sub(u'\u032f+', u'\u032f', unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)))
```

---

> Could you explain why your re.sub command does not have any +1 for ensuring that the breves are consecutive characters? (like [@Paulo Freitas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11498830/4279))

`re.sub('c+', 'c', text)` makes sure that there are no 'cc', 'ccc', 'cccc', etc in the text. Sometimes the regex does unnecessary work by replacing `'c'` with `'c'`. But the result is the same: no consecutive duplicate `'c'` in the text.

The regex from [@Paulo Freitas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11498830/4279) should also work:

```
no_duplicates = re.sub(u'(\u032f)\\1+', r'\1', unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s))
```

It performs the replacement only for duplicates. You can measure time performance and see what regex runs faster if it is a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: I was not aware of the term, `codepoint`. Then, this is what I wanted to do: convert a unicode string object into its equivalent string using codepoints. Is that correct?

Comment: @macmadness86 if you're not familiar with codepoints, you probably want to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @macmadness86: no. It is not correct. You convert one sequence of (Unicode) codepoints into another. Compare `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s)` and `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)` e.g., where `s = u'Ç'`. Here's a [codepoint for you](http://codepoints.net/U+1F384)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Could you explain why your re.sub command does not have any `+1` for ensuring that the breves are consecutive characters? (like Paulo Freitas's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460855/python-how-to-remove-duplicates-only-if-consecutive-in-a-string)

Comment: @macmadness86: I've explained how `re.sub('c+', 'c', text)` works

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [str.encode([encoding[, errors]])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) function with the [unicode_escape](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) encoding:

```
>>> s = u'freø̯̯nt'
>>> print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
b'fre\\xf8\\u032f\\u032fnt'
```

Comment: thanks but I get this error: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ~/Python/unicode to raw literals.py on line 1, but no encoding declared;`

Comment: @macmadness86: Well, which encoding is your editor using? In Python 2, ASCII is the default source code encoding - if you use something else, you need to explicitly declare it at the top of the script.

Comment: @TimPietzcker That was it! I just added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`to the top of the file and it worked. Thanks! I assume this works because I have unicode characters in my script: `freø̯̯nt`