# How do I remove two consecutive same characters from a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove consecutively same characters from a string. For example:

```
         abb --> ab
         aaab --> ab
         ababa --> ababa (since no two consecutive characters are same)
```

My code:

```
T=int(input())
l=[0]
S1=""
for i in range(T):
    S=input()
    for j in range(len(S)-1):
        if S[j]!=S[j+1]:
            if S[j] != l[len(l)-1]:
                l=[]
                l.append(S[j])
                l.append(S[j+1])
                print(l)

            for k in l:
                S1+=k
            

    print(S1)
    S1=""
    l=[0]
```

The code doesn't work for the third case (`ababa`). How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean ***at least*** 2 consecutive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove duplicates only if consecutive in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460855/how-to-remove-duplicates-only-if-consecutive-in-a-string)

Comment: Shouldn't `aaab` become `aab`? It has only once 2 consecutive `a`s...

Answer (score 2):

One concise approach would use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def clean(s):
    return ''.join(k for k, _ in groupby(s))

>>> clean("abb")
'ab'
>>> clean("aaab")
'ab'
>>> clean("ababa")
'ababa'
```

A rather simplified quadratic loop-based approach (linear in comments):

```
def clean(s):
    res = ""  # res = []
    for c in s:
        if not res or res[-1] != c:
            res += c  # res.append(c)
    return res  # return ''.join(res)
```

Comment: According to the described desired output, it should become `ab`

Comment: Q sounds like a homework assignment.  I wonder if hiding so much of the problem behind `groupby` is going to fly.

Answer (score 1):

A verbose way of doing it, may not be most efficient if the strings are large:

```py
value = 'aaaaaabbbbaaaaaacdeeeeefff'

def no_dups(value):
    r = ''
    for i in value:
        if not r or r[-1] != i:
            r += i
    return r

print(no_dups(value))
# abacdef
```

Comment: It just drop duplicates not only the connsecutive ones

Comment: @Hamza - I don't see that.  His example looks right.  Can you provide an input for which this fails?

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, we could do `re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1', string_data)`

```py
import re

test_data = 'abb aaab ababa'.split()

for data in test_data:
    print(f"{data} -->", re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1', data))
```

Comment: That is very similar. Yes!

Answer (score 1):

Came out with this code, works properly:

```
T=int(input())      #No of testcases; for testing multiple strings
S1=""
for i in range(T):
    S=input()
    for j in range(0,len(S),2):
        if j!=len(S)-1:
            if S[j]!=S[j+1]:
                S1+=S[j]
                S1+=S[j+1]
        else:
            if S1[len(S1)-1]!=S[j]:
                S1+=S[j]

    print(S1)
    S1=""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as:

```
for char in set(string):
    string = re.sub(f'{char}+', char, string)
string
```

results in

```
 abb --> ab
 aaab --> ab
 ababa --> ababa
```

Comment: Indeed thats right! I will make it more efficient!